# React Router target div id in home page

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, github-pages, react-router-dom

I am using react router specifically the HashRouter since I am trying to host my react app on github pages. Prior to using the HashRouter I was just using the BrowserRouter and I was able to target a particular div on the default (Home) route (i.e. `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />)` by its id as follows ...

```
 <li className="nav-item">
              <a
                className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                href="/#about"
                data-target="#about"
              >
                About
              </a>
            </li>
```

The above worked exactly as I had hoped by just scrolling the Home page down to the About section which had the id: #about. However, now I am using HashRouter and cannot achieve the same desired behaviour. Now when I click on the link it will just go to the Home component but will **not** scroll to the about section as it did before. Is there a simple solution to fix this? I have included snippets from the relevant code sections below...

```
    <HashRouter basename="/">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <ContextProvider>
                  <Route
                    path="/terms-and-conditions"
                    component={TermsAndConditions}
                  />
                  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
<Switch>
<HashRouter>

  <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold"
                to={{ pathname: "/", hash: "#about" }}
                data-target="#about"
              >
                About
              </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this package **React Router Hash Link**. For more info on package, visit [react-router-hash-link] [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) but the steps below should suffice.

1. Run `npm i react-router-hash-link` on your project.
2. Replace  `<Link className="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" to={{ pathname: "/", hash: "#about" }} data-target="#about"> About</Link>`
3. With `<HashLink to="/#about">About</HashLink>`